# Is the meaning of the sentence appearing in page 44 of "The Rising Sea" the following commutative diagram?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

In Vakil's book "The Rising Sea", page 43-44.

> Two covariant functors $F:\mathscr A\to \mathscr B$ and $G: \mathscr B\to  \mathscr A$ are adjoint if there is a natural bijection for all $A\in \mathscr A$ and $B\in \mathscr B$
>   $$\tau_{AB} : \operatorname{Mor}_{\mathscr B}(F(A),B)\to \operatorname{Mor}_{\mathscr A}(A,G(B)).$$
>   We say that $(F,G)$ form an adjoint pair, and that $F$ is left-adjoint to $G$ (and $G$ is right-adjoint to $F$). We say $F$ is a left adjoint (and $G$ is a right adjoint). By "natural" we mean the following. For all $f: A\to A'$ in $\mathscr A$, we require
>   $$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
> \operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr B}(F(A'),B)@>Ff^*>> \operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr B}(F(A),B)
> \\ @VV \tau_{A'B}V @VV\tau_{AB}V
> \\ \operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr A}(A',G(B))@>f^* >> \operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr A}(A,G(B))
> \end{CD}
> $$
>   to commute, and for all $g: B\to B'$ in $\mathscr B$ we want a similar commutative diagram to commute.

Is the meaning of the last sentence the following commutative diagram?

$$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr A}(A,G(B))@>Gg^*>> \operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr A}(A,G(B'))
\\ @VV \tau_{AB}^{-1}V @VV\tau_{AB'}^{-1}V
\\ \operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr B}(F(A),B)@>g^* >> \operatorname{Mor} _{\mathscr B}(F(A),B')
\end{CD}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$